# How to connect values inside two RefCells

Tags: rust, refcell

Sample code :

```
use serde_json::{json, Value};

fn main() {
  let a: Rc<RefCell<Value>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(json!({"a": "value"})));
  let v: Rc<RefCell<Vec<Value>>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(vec![]));

  // How to push a into v, but keep `a` and `v` for future uses
}
```

I want to push Value `a` into vector `v` (link pointer), but still be able to use `a` later on.

I've tried the following:

1.

```
v.borrow_mut().push(*a.borrow_mut());
```

This does not work, as `Value` does not implement Copy trait, thus could not be dereferenced

2.

```
v.borrow_mut().push(RefCell::take(&a));
```

This works, however `a` has now lost the contents. I do understand that there should only be one owner, but I'm not sure how to achieve what I need.

### The Why

I have a Value which I need to modify depending on some other data which is in a tree structure. I want to recursively walk through that other data tree, and pass along this Value to be modified.

In my function, I have this Value signature as `Rc<RefCell<Value>>`, and depending on the case I sometimes need to add nested properties, so I may need to add a property containing a vector with a new `json!({})`, and pass it as a new `Rc<RefCell<Value>>` to sub-iterations to append data to this specific subtree.

So, if you have any advice - maybe I need to change the recursive function's signature to have this data as `Rc<RefCell<&Value>>` instead, to have only one owner ? That seems like an awful lot of all sorts of references stacked upon one another, not sure which is the good way

Edit1: Updated sample to include Rc<RefCell<_>>

Comment: You can't copy `refCell` objects, consider wrapping them in a `Rc` or `Arc` which can be copied. A `Rc<RefCell<>>` is a sharable clonable mutable reference.

Comment: I see, the sample code is imprecise. Say both a and v are Rc<RefCell<_>> (which actually corresponds to my usecase)

Comment: You can `.clone()` a `Rc`, so you can use that to store multiple copies

Comment: From what I understand, `clone()` allows indeed use the same RefCell multiple times, however if I do `RefCell::take(&a)`, all of the copies will point to a RefCell which will henceforth contain only the default value (data is lost), right ?

Comment: You don't ever need to do that though since `RefCell` implements `Deref`

Comment: `Deref` only works with types implementing `Copy` trait, which is not the case here with `serde_json::value::Value` type. I wouldn't want to copy all the contents though. I'm more and more thinking that I might need `Rc<RefCell<&T>>` instead of `Rc<RefCell<T>>`, would you agree?

Comment: Good thing `RefCell` implements `DerefMut` so also works for classes that don't implemenet copy. `RefCell<&T>` would make the type immutable and create some very hard to guarentee lifetime bounds.

Comment: Oooh thats the answer !! `v.borrow_mut().push(a.borrow_mut().deref_mut().to_owned());` Works !!
Thanks a lot ! You can post it as the answer that I'll accept, if you want karma :)